# Call image from config

Tags: php, config

I am currently learning PHP and I have a problem in calling an image from a config file.

Basically, the URL for the image is defined in a config file ("config.php") like this:

```
/*** VISUAL STYLE ***/
$visual_style['background_image'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/images/bigbackground/1.jpg';
```

The function to call the image is stored in an index.php.

What should I do to call it successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What function is stored in index.php?

Comment: I'm writing a landing page which consists of an index.php and config.php; all the settings are stored in the config.php. I didn't define the background image in the CSS because I want the background image to be user-configurable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo $visual_style['background_image']; ?>">
```

or

```
<div style="background-image:<?php echo $visual_style['background_image']; ?>"></div>
```